# Curious behavior using SpanFromLeft in Grid[]

Tags: grid-layouts

I need to set up a rather complicated `Grid[]` and I've run into a curious problem.  I've reduced it to a simple example.  See the following 2 sets of code and their output:

```
    plot = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}, ImageSize -> 175];
    Grid[
     {
      {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
      {2, "x", "x", "A long title... ", 70000},
      {3, "xx", "xx", "", ""},
      {4, "xxx", SpanFromLeft, plot, SpanFromLeft},
      {5, "xxxx", SpanFromLeft, SpanFromAbove, SpanFromBoth},
      {6, "xxxxx", SpanFromLeft, SpanFromAbove, SpanFromBoth},
      {7, "xxxxxx",  SpanFromLeft, SpanFromAbove, SpanFromBoth},
      {8, "xxxxxxx", SpanFromLeft, SpanFromAbove, SpanFromBoth},
      {9, "xxxxxxxx", SpanFromLeft, SpanFromAbove, SpanFromBoth},
      {10, "xxxxxxxxx", SpanFromLeft, SpanFromAbove, SpanFromBoth}
     } ,
     Alignment -> {Left, Top}
     ]

    "-----------------------------"

    Grid[
     {
      {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
      {2, "x", "x", "A long title... ", 70000},
      {3, "xx", "xx", "", ""},
      {4, "xxx", "", plot, SpanFromLeft},
      {5, "xxxx", SpanFromLeft, SpanFromAbove, SpanFromBoth},
      {6, "xxxxx", SpanFromLeft, SpanFromAbove, SpanFromBoth},
      {7, "xxxxxx",  SpanFromLeft, SpanFromAbove, SpanFromBoth},
      {8, "xxxxxxx", SpanFromLeft, SpanFromAbove, SpanFromBoth},
      {9, "xxxxxxxx", SpanFromLeft, SpanFromAbove, SpanFromBoth},
      {10, "xxxxxxxxx", SpanFromLeft, SpanFromAbove, SpanFromBoth}
     } ,
     Alignment -> {Left, Top}
     ]
```

Output:

[image: Grids]

Both grids have 10 rows x 5 columns.  They have identical code excepting for the position at row 4 column 3:

- 1st grid has SpanFromLeft at that position.
- 2nd grid has "" at the same position.

Immediately to the left of row 4 column 3 I have the plot.

Can anyone explain why I get such different alignment in the two grids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `Frame -> All` option to both plots and you'll see why excluding `SpanFromLeft` has such an effect.  The `SpanFromLeft` is causing the cell height to adapt to the plot on its right.

With code: `{4, "xxx", SpanFromLeft, plot, SpanFromLeft}`

[image]

and with code: `{4, "xxx", "", plot, SpanFromLeft}`

[image]

Comment: I've still missed something here.  Why should the grid cell with the plot in it get affected by this difference.  Particularly as the grid cells below the plot SpanFromAbove?  Maybe I've missed something simple (not the first time).

Comment: @Jagra - There's nothing about it in the documentation.  It's just the way it works, as far as I can see.  Perhaps someone will add further detail.  If you want full control I'd recommend using `Graphics` and `Inset`.