# GraphicsGrid Format Problem with SpanFromAbove

Tags: graphics, bugs, grid-layouts

**Bug introduced in 8.0.4 or earlier and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

---

I believe this is a bug in GraphicsGrid.

```
x = Graphics[Circle[]];
g1=GraphicsGrid[{{x, x, x}, {Item[x, Background -> Red], SpanFromLeft, x}, {x, x, x}}, Frame -> All];
g2=GraphicsGrid[{{x, Item[x, Background -> Red], x}, {x, SpanFromAbove, x}, {x, x, x}}, Frame -> All];
g3=GraphicsGrid[{{x, Item[x, Background -> Red], x}, {x, SpanFromAbove, x}, {x, SpanFromAbove, x}}, Frame -> All];
Row[{g1,g2,g3},"   "]
```

[image]

SpanFromAbove do not works like expected, formats are not respected.

Changing GraphicsGrid into Grid we get:

[image]

I tested this in V9 for Win and in V10 for Mac and Win.

Comment: Agree it looks wrong.

Comment: confirm in MMa 8.0.4 and 10.0.0 under Win7 x64. Note that by default `GraphicsGrid` has `Alignment -> {Center, Center}` while `Grid` has `Alignment -> {Center, Baseline}`.

Comment: Related: [Curious behavior using SpanFromLeft in Grid[]](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15644/curious-behavior-using-spanfromleft-in-grid)

Comment: The same on MMA 10.0.1 under Mac.

Comment: The same on MMA 10.1.0 under Mac and Windows